# thread safe random number

Tags: c, multithreading, numbers, random-seed

I have a problem about generating random number in C on Windows. In brief, the thing I want to do is to generate 7 numbers that are 0 or 1. Then the function will sum these numbers, result will be the index of global defined array and the value of this index will increase by 1. But in generator function, I always get the same sequence of number. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int cells[8];

int generator(int n) {
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int random_number = rand() % 2 + 0;
        printf("%d ",random_number);
        sum += random_number;

    }
    printf("\n%d\n",sum);
    return sum;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void *data) {
    cells[generator(7)] =+ 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
        WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        printf("%i: %i\n", j, cells[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive complexity! :-) Also, in line `cells[generator(7)] =+ 1;` you probably meant to use `+=`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884311/generating-the-same-random-numbers-with-threads-in-omp/52885163#52885163 is basically the same problem, and I'm too lazy to answer it again.

Comment: See [What does `=+` mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573978/what-does-mean-in-c/)

Comment: Guys, I corrected that mistake but it isn't the problem I have. My problem is every call of the function, it prints same values. For example; first iterative in loop: 1 1 0 0 1 1 1. Second iterative :1 1 0 0 1 1 1 and so on. It always gives same values.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from "`=+ 1`" issue... there is an additional concern with the code:

Microsoft explicitly says that the seed is thread-specific (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/srand):

> The srand function sets the starting point for generating a series of pseudorandom integers in the current thread.

That implies that the seed value (/ sequence generator) is saved in thread-local storage. However, they *don't* specify what happens if you call `srand` before creating additional threads. It seems quite likely to me therefore that the thread-local storage containing the seed value will either be copied from the initializing thread - or it will simply be reinitialized with the default seed in each thread the first time you call `rand` as if you *hadn't* called `srand` at all.

In either case, all threads would end up generating the the same pseudo-random sequence anyway.

Hence, you will be better off calling `time` once, adding the thread index to that initial time value, passing the result as an argument to the thread function, then using that (thread-specific) value as the argument to `srand` *within* the thread. At least then each thread will start from a different initial seed value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a thread-safe random number. Your code always calls `rand` in a precise deterministic sequence because you wait for each thread to finish before starting the next one. Your problem is this;

```
cells[generator(7)] =+ 1;
```

This sets the cell to `+1` rather than adding one to it.

Comment: I've tried that but it is not the problem. I stil get the same numbers.